# IE8 Transparent PNG problems in Nivo Slider using background-image for Prev and Next Buttons

Tags: internet-explorer-8, png, transparency, nivo-slider

I'm using the [nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) on [our site](http://www.designlagoon.com/)

It's working great on all devices except for IE8 on XP, which due to the infamous IE transparent png issue, I get black borders around the prev and next buttons on rollover. The prev and next buttons need to be transparent pngs as they have a drop-shadow and are placed on top of transitioning images.

**The Arrows**
[image]

**The Problem IN IE8 XP**
[image]

**The HTML**

```
<div class="nivo-directionNav">
    <a class="nivo-prevNav" style="display: none;"></a>
    <a class="nivo-nextNav" style="display: none;"></a>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

/* the arrows are taken from a single sprite with a standard and active image
for prev and next with the background-position changed on rollover   */

.nivo-prevNav, .nivo-nextNav {
    width: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    }

.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0px;
    background: url("images/nivo_4_arrows.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    }


.nivo-prevNav:hover {
    background: url("images/nivo_4_arrows.png") no-repeat -80px 0;
    }
```

I have tried to implement this javascript as a fix:

```
var i;
for (i in document.images) {
if (document.images[i].src) {
    var imgSrc = document.images[i].src;
    if (imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.length-4) === '.png' || imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.length-4) === '.PNG') {
        document.images[i].style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled='true',sizingMethod='crop',src='" + imgSrc + "')";
    }
}
}
```

...as well as [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/1318344) found on a similar post on this forum but neither have proved successful.

Been wasting lots of time on this so I'd really appreciate anyone that can shed some light on a fix!

Comment: Is IE just adding a border to the link? Set border: none on the arrows and see if that solves it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but it's not a css border. The arrow graphic was created in Photoshop with a drop-shadow. The entire area of the drop-shadow which should be semi-transparent displays as solid black on IE on rollover. You can check it on Firefox / Chrome to see how it should look on rollover.

Comment: The your site link goes to the slider page. Could you fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert the following lines into '*nivo-slider.css*' (a style for no theme specified):

```
.nivo-slice
{
background: transparent;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)" !important;/* IE8 */   
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF) !important;/* IE6 & 7 */      
zoom: 1;
}
```

It works for the *slice* effect, but put this for the other effects, however in my case this solution changes the *fade* effect into a simple changing pictures effect (without fading). Maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

This javascript script will not work with images on backgrounds, only "img src"...

there are 2 ways to solve:
use "img src" and put "position:absolute" and positioning the image in the background.

OR

Make an if IE and instead of background-image use:

filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled='true',sizingMethod='crop',src='link-to-image');

keep using backgroung-image for other browsers..

Comment: I think the IE conditional statement will be my best option. However - the background images are created dynamically with the following javascript from the NIVO slider:                                     
        slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');           Any idea how i can apply the IE conditional statement to this code? -

Comment: open FIREFOX firebug inspect the element, right click on the element (inside the firebug) and copy the css path, do this to each of the images.. then..

<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
path of the css {
    backgorund:none;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled='true',sizingMethod='crop',src='link-to-image');
}
</style>
<![endif]-->